# Upsert instead of save mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections(so and temp_so).

My query:

```
db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').find({},'orderItemId').
  forEach(function(element) { db.getCollection('sale_order').save(element); });
```

i have a document with `orderItemId` 123 in temp_so. I want to check if a document with `orderItemId` exist in so then the query should update the whole document in so. If the document with orderItemId does not exist in so, it should create one.

The query should do this for all the documents in temp_so.

My current query just insert the data in so and doesn't check if the document with `orderItemId` exists or not in so. How to rectify it?

In SQL this can be written as:

```
insert into so ( select * from temp_so where orderItemId not in ( select orderItemId from so));
Update so set col = select col from temp_so where temp_so.orderItemId = so.orderItemId. 
*update for all the columns*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking the `.save()` action is already a "wrapper" around an "upsert", it's just only ever looking at the `_id` field only, and where present.

So you just need to be explicit about which field you are looking up. And also removing the existing `_id`:

```js
db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').find({},{ 'orderItemId': 1 }).
  forEach(function(element) { 
     delete element._id;
     db.getCollection('sale_order').update(
        { "orderItemId": element.orderItemId },
        element,
        { "upsert": true }
     );
 });
```

You might also consider that you don't want to replace the whole document and would rather just "insert" the first occurance only. Which is what [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) does here:

```js
db.getCollection('temp_sale_order').find({},{ 'orderItemId': 1}).
  forEach(function(element) { 
     delete element._id;
     db.getCollection('sale_order').update(
        { "orderItemId": element.orderItemId },
        { "$setOnInsert": { "orderItemid": element.orderItemId } },
        { "upsert": true }
     );
 });
```

So that basically means that any alteration within `$setOnInsert` will not actually be applied unless this is actually an "upsert" and a new document is created. If it is just a "match" then nothing in the document gets changed.

Comment: the previous answer was correct `'orderItemId'`. `{'orderItemId':1}` deletes all the other key values in document. Thanx.

Comment: @ManishGupta The second paramter in `.find()` is a projection statement that is "meant" to select just the specified fields.  Just putting in a "string" instead does not do anything. So if you didn't want to select only certain fields then omit the "projection" entirely.